# Proof that any finite group can be generated by a set of representatives of the conjugacy classes

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I have to proof that any finite group can be generated by a set of representatives of the conjugacy classes, but I still had some questions about my proof:

- Why is $G$ equal to $\bigcup_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$ if $H$ intersects all conjugacy classes?
- In $\bigcup_{g\in G/H}gHg^{-1}$ some of the sets could be equal to eachother and there could be less than $|G|/|H|$ sets. Is this a problem?

Here is my proof so far:
Suppose that $G$ is not generated by a set of representatives of its conjugacy classes.
Then there must exist a subgroup $H\subsetneq G$, that intersects all conjugacy classes of $G$.
Then we have $G =\bigcup_{g\in G}gHg^{-1}$.
Because $g_1Hg_1^{-1}=g_2Hg_2^{-1}$ if $g_1$ and $g_2$ are in the same coset of $G/H$, we can also say $G=\bigcup_{g\in G/H}gHg^{-1}$.
There are $|G|/|H|$ sets in this union, with each set having $|H|$ elements.
So the union is only equal to $G$ if all sets are disjunct.
But they all contain the identity.
So $G$ can be generated by a set of representatives of its conjugacy classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $h \in H$ is in the same conjugacy class as $x$, then this means that there is a $g \in G$ such that $ ghg^{-1}=x$, therefore $x \in gHg^{-1}$. This was your first question.

The answer to your second question is that all the sets are different, since $gHg^{-1}=g'Hg'^{-1}$ implies $\overline{g}=\overline{g'}\in G/H$. So, there is no problem.